# Updating time and position using GetTickCount() in C++

Tags: c++, winapi

**Problem:** I am attempting to update time using getTickCount without avail. 
**Situation:** I currently obtain the timedifference using getTickCount and pass it into world update method parameters. However within the update method where I update the position, a large value is passed in (even though I have divided by 1000) and so the position adds an odd 4000 to the position vector.

Code below:

Simulation.CPP:

```
    int Simulation::simControlLogic(HWND hWnd, keyEvent event)
{
    /* TO DO: add relevant code */


    if (event != QUIT)
    {
        previousTime = 0;

        frameStartTime = GetTickCount();

        if (previousTime == 0)
            previousTime = frameStartTime;

        timeDifference = (frameStartTime - previousTime)  / 1000.0f; // this generates the difference between the last and current time
        world.update(event, &graphics, timeDifference);                 // update parameters of virtual world

        gameLoopDelay(frameStartTime);

        simDisplayFrame(hWnd);          // display frame

        previousTime = frameStartTime;  //the current time is set to the previous time for the next loop step

    }

   return 1;
}
```

looking into the world Update method:

```
int WorldData::update(keyEvent kEvent, GraphicsM * pGraphicsModule, float timeStep)
    {

    //updates the particle
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        particles[i].Update(kEvent, pGraphicsModule, timeStep);
    }

    return 1;
    }
```

looking into particles Update method:

```
void ParticleModel::Update(keyEvent kEvent, GraphicsM * pGraphicsModule, float timeStep)
{
    move(timeStep);
}
```

looking into move method:

```
void ParticleModel::move(float timeStep)
{

    velocity.y = 0.5F;
    velocity.x = 0.5F;
    acceleration.x = 0.0F;
    acceleration.y = 0.0F;

    pos.x += velocity.x * timeStep; //here is the problem. I get a large value e.g 79637.1788 causing pos.x to be ridiculously large
    pos.y += velocity.y * timeStep; //here is the problem. I get a large value e.g 79637.1788 causing pos.y to be ridiculously large


}
```

Comment: What's the type of the timeDifference, frameStartTime and  previousTime members/variables ?

Comment: What, where and when is `previousTime` initialised?

Comment: Do you correctly initialize the tick count in the first frame? If not, it might be set to zero, leading to a large `timeStep` in the first iteration.

Comment: BTW: this is not directly related to your problem: the unit of `timeDifference` seems to be one second, because `GetTickCount` returns the elapsed time in milliseconds and you divide `timeDifference` by 1000.

Comment: Post real code. You set `previousTime` to 0, so then set it to `frameStartTime`, so `timeDifference` is 0...

Comment: @TimOgunmakin: your objects will move at most once per second if the precision of the `timeStep` in `ParticleModel::move` is one second.

Answer (score 0):

After moving previousTime to the simulator constructor initializing it to 0, it worked. Thanks for replies

Comment: Simpler would be to initialize it to `GetTickCount()`.